# Recursive digital sums of square integers

Tags: square-numbers

For the first 20 positive integers, the recursive digit sum (mod 9) of their squares follow a pattern of repeating 1, 4, 9, 7, 7, 9, 4, 1, 9. I wonder whether this pattern applies to all integer numbers. If it does, what will be the reason behind this phenomenon? Any suggestions?

Some examples below:

```
1, 1, 1
2, 4, 4
3, 9, 9
4, 16, 7
5, 25, 7
...
9, 81, 9
10, 100, 1
11, 121, 4
...
19, 361, 1
```

Comment: What's a recursive digit sum?  Do you just mean "iterate until you get a single digit"?  If so, you are just picking up $n^2\pmod 9$ (where, of course, you must represent $0$ by $9$).  Should say:  I don't understand your "examples".

Comment: Yes, you are right. For example, for 19, its square is 361 and its recursive digit sum (mod 9) is 3 + 6 + 1 => 1 + 0 (10) => 1.

Comment: In general, the iterated digit sum of $n$ is always just $n\pmod 9$, with the substitution I mentioned.  Nothing special about squares.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your comment correctly or I did not explain my question clearly enough. My questions is around the **repeating** of `1, 4, 9, 7, 7, 9, 4, 1, 9` as sequential numbers. So given "1 to N", the result keeps repeating `1, 4, 9, 7, 7, 9, 4, 1, 9`? (This is actually asked for my son who found this phenomenon :D)

Comment: But of course $\{n^2\}\pmod 9$ is periodic.  That follows from the remark $(a+9)^2\equiv a^2 \pmod 9$.  The same claim would hold for $n^3, n^4, n^{171}$ and so on.  The least period might be smaller than $9$, but $9$ is always a period.

Comment: Also, the fact that $(9-n)^2 \equiv (-n)^2 \equiv n^2 \pmod{9}$ explains the mirror symmetry within one period.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Let's denote the iterated digit sum by $S(n)$.  It is well known, and easy to demonstrate, that $n\equiv S(n)\pmod 9$.  Indeed, $S(n)$ is essentially equal to the remainder you get on dividing $n$ by $9$, with the proviso that if the remainder is $0$, $S(n)=9$.

Now, consider the sequence $\mathscr S=\{S(n^2)\}$.  Since $(n+9)^2\equiv n^2\pmod 9$ we see that  $\mathscr S$ is periodic with period $9$.  A priori there might be a period smaller than $9$ but in this case there is not.

The same argument would apply to any power, not just squares.  For instance the sequence of the digit sum of cubes is $\{1,8,9,1,8,9,\cdots\}$ which has period $3$ (note that $3$ divides $9$ so $9$ is still a period, just not the least one).  Or you could take fifth powers to get the periodic sequence $$\{\overline {1,5,9,7,2,9,4,8,9}\}$$

and so on.